# how to convert numpy ndarray containing multiple png images to float

Tags: numpy

Here is my code
It picks up 1.png , 2.png , ... , 34.png from folder 'path_to_image_directory' .
Makes an array which I want to convert to float .
You can save the file as sample.py and run it using 'python sample.py' .

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

original = []
num = 34 #number of images in directory
directory = 'path_to_image_directory\\'
for i in range(num):
     img = cv2.imread(directory + str(i) + '.png')
     print('original datatype:',type(original))
     original.append(img)
np.save('inddeoriginal',original)
original = np.load('inddeoriginal.npy')
print('original datatype:',original.dtype)
print('original datatype:',type(original))
original = original.astype('float32')
original = (original - 127.5) / 127.5
```

Here I get the error

> original = original.astype('float32')
>  ValueError: setting an
>   array element with a sequence.

Where am I going wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: `original` was a `list` containing `str` elements before you save it to `inddeoriginal.npy`, after you load it with `np.load( )` statement, it is an `array` containing `str` type of objects. If I understand your questions clearly, I don't think you can convert a `str` object to a `float` object unless the `str` object only contains numbers, e.g., original = ['35.2', '69'].

Comment: the above code worked when I had files 0.png , 1.png , ... , 33.png .
Original contains an array of numbers which are RGB value for each pixel.

Comment: I am getting all zeroes in npy file though the code does not give error .

Comment: Also , when I do print('raw img begins_',img,'_ends'). I see all zeroes .